# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '100')

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mern, dashboard, sidebar

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { ProSidebar, Menu, MenuItem } from 'react-pro-sidebar';
import { Box, IconButton, Typography, useTheme } from '@mui/material';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css';
import { tokens } from '../../theme';

const Sidebar = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('Dashboard');

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        '& .pro-sidebar-inner': {
          background: `${colors.primary[400]} !important`,
        },
        '& .pro-icon-wrapper': {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent !important',
        },
        '& .pro-inner-item': {
          padding: '5px 35px 5px 20px !important',
        },
        '& .pro-inner-item:hover': {
          color: '#868dfb !important',
        },
        '& .pro-menu-item.active': {
          color: '#6870fa !important',
        },
      }}
    >
      <ProSidebar collapsed={isCollapsed}>
        <Menu iconShape="square">
          {/* LOGO AND MENU ICON */}
          <MenuItem
            onClick={() => setIsCollapsed(!isCollapsed)}
            icon={isCollapsed ? <MenuOutlinedIcon /> : undefined}
            style={{
              margin: '10px 0 20px 0',
              color: colors.grey[100],
            }}
          >
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </ProSidebar>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

This is Sidebar code

I will be able get the output as dark and light theme. and the sidebar , navbar  and the profile user is of left side

but I am getting blank while page and I didn't get any error in the terminal.

Comment: Hard to say without stack trace, but it may be that "colors.grey" is not defined.

Comment: No.., I have defined colors.gray